# Parsing JSON in android to add markers in Google Map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have an url,get and response given. I have to parse the JSON and show the locations in Map in android. I dont need you to code. I am new in JSON. please tell me some steps how i can do that. how should i start and which steps i should take?

Url: "Some url"

Sending data:

```
{
    "tag": "getAvailableDriver",
    "lat": 41.022348,
    "lng": -91.966721
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "success": "1",
            "driver": [
                {
                    "id": "768",
                    "lat": "41.022848",
                    "lon": "-91.966884",
                    "recorded_datetime": "2014-07-20 20:18:03",
                    "user_id": "403",
                    "cabbi_state": "OnJob",
                    "vehicleType": "Black Cab",
                    "driver_name": "black cab driver",
                    "pic_name": "userimage/403.jpg",
                    "rating": "0",
                    "car_model": "this",
                    "number_sit": "4",
                    "distance": 0.035574527536789
                }
            ],
            "operator": [],
            "nearestdistance": [
                {
                    "distance": 0.03541809,
                    "time": 5
                }
            ],
            "car_models": [
                "Taxi"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want anyone of you to guide me or show me the way. And also please someone tell me what will be the use of "send data" here. What is the use? I promise i will not ask any basic questions after i catch the grip. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the  parsed data in an array, and for what I can see, there's a lot of tags in the JSON object. I suggest you to create an object of the type "Driver" or "Car", and then save all the data in that object. Once you have the data parsed and saved in an Array of the type of your object (Let's say an array of "Drivers" then you can use the info to add it into the Map.

Comment: Yes, i already done that. I parsed the data. Now can u please help me in how i add them in google maps?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions%29  You can use this method in the Maps class